# MongoDB: find execution time for count() command on millions of records in a collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I am trying to find time required to perform a count() on a collection which is consisting of millions of testdata records, with following scenario:-

1) From 1st Mongo shell I am inserting millions of records into collection using a code

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i){ 
  db.unicorns.insert({name: 'sampleName', gender: 'm', weight: '440' });
}
```

2) From 2ndMongo shell I am trying to find count() on that collection(**Imp:** while insertion is still getting executed on 1st Mongo Shell)

```
db.unicorns.count()
```

I researched but found that explain() and stats() cannot be applied to count() command.

some

I  need to find out how much time it takes to count() when there are insertions going on collection(something like a live scenario)?

Is there any other good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoDB has a built-in profiller that you can enable via:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Instead of '2' you can choose any option from the list bellow:

- **0** - the profiler is off, does not collect any data. mongod always writes operations longer than the slowOpThresholdMs threshold to its log.
- **1** - collects profiling data for slow operations only. By default slow operations are those slower than 100 milliseconds.
  You can modify the threshold for “slow” operations with the slowOpThresholdMs runtime option or the setParameter command. See the Specify the Threshold for Slow Operations section for more information.
- **2** - collects profiling data for all database operations.

And you can see the results of your queries by checking the **system.profile** collection in MongoDB..

**EDIT:**

If you want to test performance you could use the following snippets of code that can be executed from the mongo console:

```
> for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) { db.countTest.insert({a: i % 10}) }
> db.countTest.ensureIndex({a:1})
> db.countTest.count({a: 1})
> db.countTest.count()
> db.countTest.find().count()
```

And my conclusions are as following:

1. **adding an index** (appart from the id) returned the count for **10 million records** in around **170ms**
2. **counting by id** (count without any query) returned the count in **less than a millisecond**
3. **counting by id with cursor** (note that the .find() will act as a cursor over the collection) returned the count in **less than a millisecond**

So the **more indexes** your collection has the **slower your query will be**. If you **count by _id it will be instant**, if you have a **composite index** it will **scale based on the number of indexes**.

Comment: I have gone through profiling previously, Let me again give it a shot

Comment: @swapnilsawant perhaps you can post your system.profile logs here and I can help you read them

Comment: Thanks.  I am curently stuck with different stuff. I will come back to this and post the logs and if it works I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It did worked. I used db.setProfilingLevel(1) .Glad to see that mongodb returns count on 10 million records(while in insertion mode) in less than 100 milliseconds. None of my count query were logged in system.profile. I also exported system.profile collection as a csv file and verified. Thanks Man.

Comment: Here is one record of count() command from logs..{ "op" : "command", "ns" : "learn.$cmd", "command" : { "count" : "unicorns", "query" : {  }, "fields" : {  } }, "keyUpdates" : 0, "numYield" : 0, "lockStats" :{ "timeLockedMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(10), "w" : NumberLong(0) }, "timeAcquiringMicros" : { "r" : NumberLong(1), "w" : NumberLong(1) } }, "responseLength" :
 48, "millis" : 0, "execStats" : {  }, "ts" : ISODate("2014-09-09T18:05:42.706Z"), "client" : "127.0.0.1", "allUsers" : [ ], "user" : "" }  .Does it mean it took 0 millis to count on collection with 10 million records.

Comment: @swapnilsawant depending on the content of your collection it might have been very fast, probably less than a milisecond

Comment: Oh ya might be I have just included 3 fields. Right.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

The easier way would be

```
function timeCount(database, collection) {
  db = db.getSiblingDB(database);
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  db.collection.count();
  print("msecs taken: "+ (new Date().getTime() - start) );
 }
```

Now you can call the function with

```
 timeCount("yourDB","unicorns")
```

You can put the function into a js file and load it via the `--shell` parameter or you can put it into your `~/.mongorc.js` and call it with every db and collection.